# U-Boot Bootup error

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, boot-loader, u-boot

I'm running a Debian Linux on a Cubietruck, running off a SD card.

When I power on, I get the following error:

```
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 46000000 ...                                                                                                                Image Name:   Linux-3.4.105+                                          
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)                   
Data Size:    5359176 Bytes = 5.1 MiB                                 
Load Address: 40008000                                                
Entry Point:  40008000                                                
Verifying Checksum ... OK                                             
ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree                   
Could not find a valid device tree                                    
reading boot.scr                                                      

** Unable to read file boot.scr **                                                                                                                              Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...                                    

** Unrecognized filesystem type **                                                                                                                              Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...                                    

** Unrecognized filesystem type **                                                                                                                              Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...                                    

** Unrecognized filesystem type **                                                                                                                              reading script.bin                                                    
46240 bytes read in 30 ms (1.5 MiB/s)                                 
reading uImage                                                        
5359240 bytes read in 274 ms (18.7 MiB/s)                             

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 48000000 ...                                                                                                                Image Name:   Linux-3.4.105+                                          
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)                   
Data Size:    5359176 Bytes = 5.1 MiB                                 
Load Address: 40008000                                                
Entry Point:  40008000                                                
Verifying Checksum ... OK                                             
Loading Kernel Image ... OK                                           

Starting kernel ...
```

The system does eventually boot, but it seems like it first tries to read from `boot.src`, but then somehow finds the correct image file and boots fine.

I just want to remove this error. Could somebody please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the U-Boot command line console, you can enter *printenv* to see U-Boot's environment variables.  Some of these variables define the commands that are run at boot time - beginning with *bootcmd*.

Based on the output you've provided, it appears U-Boot is trying different load commands for different filesystems - for example, *ext2load* vs *fatload*.  As such, it fails to mount it as ext2; then later succeeds - presumably with FAT load commands.

[The details of this process are described here](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/u-boot-sunxi/wiki#bootscr-support).

In any case, it is possible to prevent these errors by modifying the *bootcmd* variable in your U-Boot environment so that it first attempts the configuration which you are using for your system and avoids attempting commands that are going to fail with your configuration.